# How to make this command only work for certain roles

Tags: discord.js

I need this clear command to only work for a certain role.

I'm pretty new to JS and a lot of the questions similar are outdated
or not relevant to my question

```js
bot.on('message', message => {

  if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'clear':
      if (!args[1]) return message.reply('Error, Please define a number of messages to delete')
      message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
      break;

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `some()` on the `GuildMember`'s roles to see if they have the role

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'clear':
      if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'RoleName')) return
      if (!args[1]) return message.reply('Error, Please define a number of messages to delete')
      message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
      break;
  }
})
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the exact name of the role? emojis and caps included?

Comment: yeah spelled the role name perfectly

Comment: Ok for some reason is started to work, thanks alot my friend.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the role ID, you can check if the user has that role with [`Collection#has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=has).

```js
bot.on('message', message => {

  if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'clear':
      if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(ROLE_ID))
        return;
      if (!args[1]) return message.reply('Error, Please define a amount of messages to delete')
      message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
      break;

  }
});
```

This will keep working even if you change the name/order of the role. You can get the role ID by activating developer mode (in settings, under "Appearance"), right-clicking on the role and selecting "Copy ID".

Comment: do i just stick the role id in the ROLE_ID brackets?

Comment: Replace `ROLE_ID` like this: `... cache.has("123456789123"))`.

Comment: even with the role assigned the clear command and error message do not work